# Саб меню выровнять по горизонтали

Tags: html, css

Сделал [вот такое меню](http://jsfiddle.net/pmng54gb/9/), при наведении на главный пункт1 появляется саб меню, оно начинается у пункт1 и заканчивается у пункт4. При нажатии на пункт2 или 3 саб меню сдвигается вправо. Как сделать так что бы саб меню оставалось всегда фиксировано под главным меню и не сдвигалось?

Код саб меню:

```
    .mainnav li ul{
    display: none;
}

.mainnav li:hover ul{
        display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;

}

.mainnav li:hover ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 210px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 60px;

}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5dvL7t59/ - так?

Comment: @soledar10 в общем да, но тогда меню выезжает за пределы wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так?

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.wrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainnav {
    list-style:none;
    max-width:1180px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height:43px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.mainnav li {
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.mainnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 0px 18px 0px;
    outline: none;
    border-width: 2px 0;
    border-style: solid none;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 1px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-style: solid none;
    border-color: #8a3536 #000 #8a3637;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: linear-gradient(#ad3a3e, #9d1011) #E38916;
    transition: 0.2s;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:normal;
}
.mainnav li a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
.mainnav li ul {
    display: none;
}
.mainnav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute; left: 10px;    
    width: 1000px;
}
.mainnav li:hover ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 210px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    height: 60px;
}
/*.mainnav li:hover ul li:nth-child(1n),
.mainnav li:hover ul li:hover ul li:nth-child(1n){
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}*/

.mainnav li:hover ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px 0px 18px 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245) linear-gradient(#e1e1e1, #dadada);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainnav li:hover ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
.mainnav li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.mainnav li:hover ul li:hover ul li {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="mainnav">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт1</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ПунктПунктПункт ПунктПунктПункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт2</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>

                    <ul class="third">
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>

                    <ul class="third">
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>

                    <ul class="third">
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>

                    <ul class="third">
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт3</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">РКО</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Пункт</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Пункт</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Пункт</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: а как вы сделали так что бы не вылетало за пределы wrap?

Comment: родителю ul - position: relative;  submenu - left: 10px; и изменил margin-left and margin-right на 5px

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.third{
   margin-left: -10px; 
}
```

Comment: Добавить каждому вложенному списку класс?

Comment: Похоже на то. А зачем объявлять классы и не использовать их?

Comment: тоже верно, но думал может думал есть какая-нибудь функция, а то к каждому списку добавлять класс... Это у меня их не много, а бывают вложенность и побольше

Comment: Ну если классы для <ul>  идентичны, то используй одно имя для всех.

Comment: да, но margin-left для них нужно будет каждый свой задавать по этому все равно нужно к каждому списку задавать свой класс